# Wordpress Site Images not displaying in IE11 & Firefox Browser

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an interesting problem with [this website](http://coton-in-the-elms.derbyshire.sch.uk).  When the site is viewed through Chrome or Safari, all images are displayed & the site appears as intended.

When the site is viewed in Firefox (V54) & reportedly in IE11, neither the logo, nor any other images are visible on the page.

When I inspect the code in Firefox, I can see the images in the code, so there isn't an inherent issue with the client device accessing the image:

[image: Logo]

[image: Head Portrait]

Any thoughts as to what would be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys.  Managed to fix this (which is probably why user3080315 you saw everything working OK.

The issue was with the CSS.  A friend spotted the problem:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);  
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}
```

Should become:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
}
```

filter: url(#drop-shadow); being the line causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Works on my laptop. Try to clear the cache.

Comment: This may have been post fix.